# Javascript .find() not working under all the IE browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

I have some JS code converts all the HTML dropdown to a bootstrap dropdown:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#primary').each(function(i, e) {
        if (!($(e).data('convert') == 'no')) {
            $(e).hide().wrap('<div style="display:inline-block;" class="btn-group" id="select-group-' + i + '" />');
            var select = $('#select-group-' + i);
            var current = ($(e).val()) ? $(e).val(): 'Category';

            select.html('<input type="hidden" value="' + $(e).val() + '" name="' + $(e).attr('name') + '" id="' + $(e).attr('id') + '" class="' + $(e).attr('class') + '" /><a data-toggle="dropdown" style="border-radius:4px 0px 0px 4px; margin-right:0px;" class="btn" href="javascript:;">' + current + '</a><a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="javascript:;"><span class="caret"></span></a><ul style="max-height:300px; overflow-y:scroll; overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;" class="dropdown-menu"></ul>');

            $(e).find('option').each(function(o,q) {
                if($(q).attr('value') > 0) {
                    if($(q).attr('value') == 30 || $(q).attr('value') == 17 || $(q).attr('value') == 185 ||  $(q).attr('value') == 196 || $(q).attr('value') == 197 ) {
                        select.find('.dropdown-menu').append('<li style="background-color:#FFFACD;"><a href="javascript:;" data-value="' + $(q).attr('value') + '">' + $(q).text() + '</a></li>');
                    } else {
                        select.find('.dropdown-menu').append('<li><a href="javascript:;" data-value="' + $(q).attr('value') + '">' + $(q).text() + '</a></li>');
                    }
                }
                if ($(q).attr('selected')) select.find('.dropdown-menu li:eq(' + o + ')').click();
            });

            select.find('.dropdown-menu a').click(function() {
                select.find('input[type=hidden]').val($(this).data('value')).change();
                select.find('.btn:eq(0)').text($(this).text());
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I checked the IE console, there is no error showing up at all...

It's showing up fine in Webkit browsers like safari/Chrome but not IE.
In IE (IE 10), the dropdown is empty like this: (Empty  in html)

[image]

Which in safari, it's like this:

[image]

---

**UPDATES:**

After more debugging, the problem is here...Looks like the line `$(e).find('option').each(function(o,q) {` is not working in IE since all the codes inside are not operating.  **The problem is that `.find()`. I changed it to `.children('option')` or `.children()`, all not working in IE.** I'm using jQuery 1.7.2.

```
$(e).find('option').each(function(o,q) {
...
}
```

Comment: Have you set a break point and walked through the code?

Comment: The fact that there are no errors doesn't mean that the code will do what you want it to do. Try stepping through the JS code line by line. See [Using the F12 Developer Tools to Debug JavaScript Errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg699336%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: It's not an answer, but this rings alarm bells `$('#primary').each(` an ID should be unique, so using `.each` on an ID is just wrong.. use a class instead of an ID to target more than one element

Comment: You should not be reading value with `attr('value')`, use `val()`

Comment: It might be helpful to add IE version where the bug is turning up. IE8 and IE10 have different "good guesses".

Comment: @FDL - I use that technique all the time to create a closure so that I only execute certain code (and keep it encapsulated) if a certain element is found on the page. That appears to be the exact same thing the OP is doing.

Comment: @Marcus Thank you I'm using IE10 for test now. But I'm not positive that it's gonna work in IE8..

Comment: @epascarello Thank you for your suggestion. But it's still not working.

Comment: @Adam - I guess that would work, never thought of that.. I just go with `if($('#foo').length) { ... }`

Comment: @FDL Thank you for your help. I don't think it's the problem. I changed the code and make sure i have only 1 "#primary" inside the page and it's still not working :-(

Comment: Are the different options in DOM if you check with IE developer tool inspector? If they aren't you know it's JS, if they are it's CSS.

Comment: @Marcus It's the JS issue. In IE, the whole <ul> is empty in DOM.

Comment: have you tried cutting down the code into smaller chunks so you can test each bit independantly. That will help you narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: @FDL - I used to do that too, but chances are, if that element exists, you'll want to use some code that doesn't need to be in the same closure as everything else, the benefit of $('#foo').each(function() { }) is that you get the if check and a new closure at the same time.

Comment: `$(q).attr('value')` .... change this to `$(q).val()`

Comment: @Spudley Yeah i did change this but it's not working as well. The problem is that .find(). I changed it to .children('option') or .children(), all not working in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the dropdown `ul` element and check if the lis are there, it seems to be a CSS problem, which is very common on IE.

Try giving the ul ant its elements a `float: left`; and a `width`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But the <ul>is empty in DOM. So it's not a CSS issue. :-(